# How to install the version of Jupyter Notebook that includes a debugger

Tags: debugging, jupyter-notebook, conda, jupyter-lab

Or is it JupyterLab that includes a notebook-like function that contains the debuggger?  I have Windows 10 and Conda and would like to install this in a new environment.

Answer (score 0):

JupyterLab now ships with a Debugger front-end by default.
See [Debugger in JupyterLab documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html).

You can try it in JupyterLab 3.4 by clicking [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/jtpio/dc217fb83255f54bf826a3804f5a0d7c/HEAD?urlpath=lab). When the temporary, remote sessions spins up, open a notebook and click on the bug icon in the upper right side just **above the notebook**. Toggle open the debug panel by clicking on the larger bug icon on the right side bar.
JupyterLab 3.4 is the latest stable release and so things will look a little different than the documentation.

You can bring the short debugger tutorial notebook into your running session by running the following code in a cell in a notebook:

```
!curl -o debugger.ipynb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyterlab/debugger/dfd6bf9d51a7a0cd78ca54f4173fcf527bd4d7fd/examples/index.ipynb
```

The notebook will show up in the file navigator panel on the left side shortly after running that. Double-click on it to work through it.